# How can I add multiple non-consecutive cells to Name Manager in Excel using Python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I am trying to add multiple cells, which are not always consecutive, in only one Name in Excel Name Manager using Python. You can see an example of what I want to do in the attached screenshot.

[image: example]

I have tried the Python libraries **openpyxl** and **XlsxWriter**, but both libraries can only define a specific cell or a specific range.

Examples

- openpyxl

```
specific_cell = DefinedName('specific_cell', attr_text='Sheet1!$C$8')
specific_range = DefinedName('specific_range', attr_text='Sheet1!$C$8:$J$13')
```

- XlsxWriter

```
workbook.define_name('specific_cell', '=Sheet1!$G$1')
workbook.define_name('specific_range', '=Sheet1!$G$1:$H$10')
```

Is there any way to add to Name Manager something more complicated than the above?

Based on the attached screenshot something like

```
workbook.define_name('complex_range','=Sheet1!$B$3:$E$8;Sheet1!$B$12:$C$16;Sheet1!$B$19;Sheet1!$H$12:$I$16')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These will work for each module, the common factor being comma rather than semi-colon?

**Xlsxwriter**:

```
workbook.define_name("test", "=Sheet1!$B$3:$E$8,Sheet1!$B$12:$C$16,Sheet1!$H$12:$I$16,Sheet1!$B$19")
```

**Xlwings**:

```
workbook.names.add(name="test", refers_to="=Sheet1!$B$3:$E$8,Sheet1!$B$12:$C$16,Sheet1!$H$12:$I$16,Sheet1!$B$19")
```

**Openpyxl**:

```
workbook.defined_names.add(DefinedName("test", attr_text="Sheet1!$B$3:$E$8,Sheet1!$B$12:$C$16,Sheet1!$H$12:$I$16,Sheet1!$B$19"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The issue was the **semicolon (;)**. When I replaced it with the **comma (,)** it worked as expected!

Comment: Excel often garbles stuff in the GUI so it's always best to look at XML source files.